# Rating-based discussion site for 2011: digg vs phpbb layout style?

Tags: website-design, forum

I'm building a rating-based discussion site.

Basically, it consist in a forum were people can create topics and reply to them (and also rate them).

I have approximately 10 topic categories.

I have two layouts in mind: one is phpbb-like, the other is digg-like:

**digg style:**

[image]

phpbb style:

[image]

Which one is more appealing for modern users (2011)?
Which one is more efficient according to UX design?

Comment: Have you checked out Vanilla? It has a pretty awesome (but slightly unrefined) UI

Comment: @melee It looks pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Digg style definitely.**

It is much more easy to scan through the information and creates a lot less visual noise.
It also provides more information, such as the number of likes and replies.